# MySQL calculate run time after filtering duplicate start / stop events

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn MySQL on the fly, but I simply cant find a way through this.

I am using MariaDB 10.3.21

I am pushing data from my solarsystem into a MySQL database, the main table looks like this:

| DateTime | EventDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 09:00:01 | blah |
| 01/01/21 09:00:01 | blah |
| 01/01/21 09:00:02 | Generator Start |
| 01/01/21 09:00:03 | blah |
| 01/01/21 09:00:04 | Generator Start |
| 01/01/21 10:05:02 | Generator Stop |
| 01/01/21 10:05:02 | blah |
| 01/01/21 10:05:03 | Generator Stop |

**Desired outcome**: I want a table that tracks the running total of generator running time, I would use this for maintenance scheduling, fuel checks etc.

**Problem statement**: for each generator start and stop event there are multiple entries normally a few seconds apart.

My approach so far:

I did two queries to insert only generator events into a separate table, which now looks like this

| DateTime | Start | Stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 09:00:02 | Generator Start |  |
| 01/01/21 09:00:04 | Generator Start |  |
| 01/01/21 10:05:02 | Generator Stop | Generator Stop |
| 01/01/21 10:05:03 |  | Generator Stop |

** Updated with desired outcome **

ultimate outcome is to generate a table like:

| DateTime | Start | Stop | Run time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 09:00:02 | Generator Start |  |  |
| 01/01/21 10:05:04 |  | Generator Stop | 1:05 |
| 01/01/21 11:05:02 | Generator Start |  |  |
| 01/01/21 11:025:03 |  | Generator Stop | 0:20 |

I am thinking that if I can use "rounded time" using this to make a unique key with the event description and the rounded time I could stop the duplicate entries from being generated in the table:

```
sec_to_time(floor((time_to_sec(`GeneratorRunTime`.`EventTime`) + 450) / 900) * 900)
```

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. Show desired output for shown sample data strictly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Suffice to say that, in MySQL, nothing is ever improved by a VIEW